# Spring Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter does not have a registered order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm attempting to make spring security filterchain working with a RemoteIpFilter.

The current error message is.

```
Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Filter class 
org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter does not have a registered order and cannot be added without a specified order. Consider using addFilterBefore or addFilterAfter instead.
```

If I remove the RemoteIpFilter the configuration works perfectly.

Not many examples of RemoteIpFilter outside of a spring boot environment.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private static final String X509_CERTIFICATE_NAME = "cert";
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SpringSecurityConfig.class);

@Autowired
SecurityConfig securityConfig;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilter(preauthProcessingFilter())
        .csrf().disable() // there is a custom CSRF Filter
        .addFilter(remoteIpFilter())
        .authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider())
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK)))
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionAuthenticationFailureHandler(sessionAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
            .maximumSessions(securityConfig.getMaximumSessionsPerUser())
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            ;
}

@Bean
public AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter preauthProcessingFilter() throws Exception{
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(X509_CERTIFICATE_NAME);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public RemoteIpFilter remoteIpFilter() {
    RemoteIpFilter filter = new RemoteIpFilter();
    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think exception which you got clearly tells what should you do:
`Consider using addFilterBefore or addFilterAfter instead.`

But first let's take a lool at [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M5/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilter(javax.servlet.Filter)):
addFilter(javax.servlet.Filter filter) - Adds a Filter that must be an instance of or extend one of the Filters **provided within the Security framework**.

You filter `RemoteIpFilter` isn't spring provided filter, because it's from apache.

You have two approaches to solve it:
1. You can wrap `RemoteIpFilter` with spring filter class like `GenericFilterBean`
2. Or you can use one of thoose method instead of `addFilter(filter)`:
`addFilterBefore(filter, class)`
`addFilterAfter(filter, class)`
`addFilterAt(filter, class)`

Also take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter) article it might be helpful

Comment: After updating  Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean